# How to sum dates to a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to sum into a brand new column the result of a nba match `(nba database)` Ex: If `puntos_local > puntos_visitante` the column `puntos` will be incremented by `3`. If the result is equal then sum only `1`

```
SELECT `equipo_local`, 
(case 
    when `puntos_local` > `puntos_visitante`
    then puntos=puntos+3 
    when `puntos_local` = `puntos_visitante`
    then puntos=puntos+1 
  end) AS puntos  
  FROM `partidos`

WHERE temporada LIKE "07/08"
-- GROUP BY `equipo_local`
ORDER BY puntos DESC, partidos.equipo_local
```

I also have tried something like:

```
SELECT `equipo_local`,
  Sum(Case ( When `puntos_local` > `puntos_visitante` Then  puntos=puntos+3 Else 0 End)) As puntos
 ,Sum(Case ( When `puntos_local` = `puntos_visitante` Then puntos=puntos+1 Else 0 End)) As puntos
  FROM `partidos`
WHERE temporada LIKE "07/08"
-- GROUP BY `equipo_local`
ORDER BY puntos DESC, partidos.equipo_local
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJkER.jpg
[image: .]
I would like to have an overall score summed by every match.
If `puntos_local` >  `puntos_visitante` the column `puntos` will be puntos=puntos+3
If it's a draw I would like to only sum `1`.

And as a final result I would like to have the overall score of the season. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `equipo_local`,

  Sum(puntos + 
         (Case When `puntos_local` > `puntos_visitante` Then 3 Else 0 End)
  ) As puntos_x,

 ,Sum(puntos + 
         (Case When `puntos_local` = `puntos_visitante` Then 1 Else 0 End)
  ) As puntos_y

FROM `partidos`
WHERE temporada LIKE "07/08"
-- GROUP BY `equipo_local`
ORDER BY puntos DESC, partidos.equipo_local
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT equipo_local, 
SUM(case 
    when puntos_local > puntos_visitante
    then 3 
    when puntos_local = puntos_visitante
    then 1
    else 0 
  end) AS puntos  
  FROM partidos

WHERE temporada LIKE "07/08"
GROUP BY equipo_local
ORDER BY puntos DESC, partidos.equipo_local
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need update

```
update partidos
set puntos= case when puntos_local>puntos_visitante then puntos+3 
             when puntos_local=puntos_visitante then puntos+1 
   else puntos end
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't have a column called puntos. But I want to create it for showing the result I want. I was trying to see if I could do that without phisically creating it into the database. :)

Comment: @jose9988 share your tables data and expected output in question

Answer (score 0):

SELECT `equipo_local`, 
SUM((case 
    when `puntos_local` > `puntos_visitante`
    then 3 
    when `puntos_local` = `puntos_visitante`
    then 1 
  end)) AS puntos
  FROM `partidos`

WHERE temporada LIKE "07/08"
GROUP BY equipo_local
ORDER BY puntos DESC, partidos.equipo_local